# ExtTextOutW() with ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE failed to capture the record

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, .emf

I am working on a sample in this I am creating a EMF file with some text in it.
To add a text I am using the API ExtTextOutW() with ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE option.

Return value of this API is TRUE. But when I open the EMF file the text is not present.
Then I saw the records. There is no entey for the ExtTextOutW.

Bellw is the code.

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

RECT Rect = {0, 0, 21590, 27940};

//Create the EMF file DC
HDC hEMFDC  = ::CreateEnhMetaFile(hDC, L"c:\\del\\1.emf", &Rect, L"Test");
if (NULL != hEMFDC)
{
    RECT Rect = {0, 0, 300, 155};
    HBRUSH hb = CreateSolidBrush(0X00FFFF00);

    FillRect(hEMFDC, &Rect, hb);
    DeleteObject(hb);

    int dx[12] = {25,25,25,25,25,25, 25,25,25,25,25,25};                    
    WCHAR wcsBuffer[] = L"Text Message";

    ExtTextOutW(hEMFDC, 10, 10, ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE, NULL, wcsBuffer, wcslen(wcsBuffer), dx);

    HENHMETAFILE hmf = CloseEnhMetaFile(hEMFDC); 
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hmf);
    hEMFDC = NULL;
}

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
```

Please let me know any thing I am doing wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the documentation for `ExtTextOut[W]` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), especially the part for the flags like **ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE**:

> Reserved for system use. If an application sets this flag, it loses
>   international scripting support and in some cases it may display no
>   text at all.

Just try it without this flag.